# Compile gcc 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 (under compiler gcc 5.4.0)

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc, glib

I am on **Ubuntu 16.04** and with `gcc-5.4.0` already installed.

I am trying to build the `gcc-3.2` compiler according to [this tutorial](http://www.tellurian.com.au/whitepapers/multiplegcc.php) as I need it to compile `glib-1.2.10`, to build `gtk-1.2.10`, to run `phoebe-0.29d` astronomy software.

During the `make` command step of building the `gcc-3.2` compiler, I get the following errors:

```
Makefile:3282: recipe for target 'read-rtl.o' failed
make[1]: *** [read-rtl.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bart/gobj/gcc'
Makefile:1601: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

According to [this tutorial](http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_scratch/chapter05/gcc.html), I have to apply two patches (`gcc-3.2.patch` and the `gcc-3.2-nofixincludes-2.patch`) that resolve issues with incompatibility of macro commands between `gcc` versions, but there is no link for the second one that I can find.

Any help applying the patches or building 'gcc-3.2' would be much appreciated.

Comment: The patches are here - http://oss.sgi.com/LDP/LDP/lfs/html/chapter03/packages.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the immediate response. Unfortunately none of the patches can be downloaded because it says they don't exist. I tried the http links and also to wget the ftp but with the same result.

Comment: Also i found this link http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/patches/downloads/gcc/ and lucky me but only the gcc-3.2 patches seem to do not exist :P . Maybe i could try to install the gcc-2.95.3 because there are some files as patches but there isn't a guide and i'm not sure if they are for the same purpose i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier : Get the old packages.deb → 1) gtk+1.2 → http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+1.2/ ... 2) glib1.2 → http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib1.2/

Or use the patches : `glib1.2_1.2.10-17build1.diff.gz`, `gtk+1.2_1.2.10-17build1.diff.gz` from the links to compile with a later compiler. I just did with gcc-4.9.2 ( Took a minute each ). May also be possible with Ubuntu 16.04 . Available for 16.04 are : `sudo apt install gcc-4.7 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.9`

---

Howto build : ( But I would just install the two packages_amd64.deb )

```
cd glib-1.2.10/
zcat glib1.2_1.2.10-17build1.diff.gz | patch -p1
export CC=gcc-4.9 && ./configure --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install

cd gtk+-1.2.10/
zcat gtk+1.2_1.2.10-17build1.diff.gz | patch -p1
export CC=gcc-4.9 && ./configure --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

Be aware that you may have to use an earlier version of gcc in Ubuntu 16.04  : `sudo apt install gcc-4.7` . The export commands are then `export CC=gcc-4.7`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your response! I installed the gcc-4.9.2 but could you please tell me which  commands to use exactly in order to patch the glib and gtk+ with the .diff files ?  Also for the sake of completeness the .deb files of the easier way i have to use are:  libglib1.2_1.2.10-17build1_amd64.deb and libgtk1.2_1.2.10-17_amd64.deb ?

Comment: I edited the anwer to include the build of glib-1.2.10 and gtk+-1.2.10

Comment: I really thank you. I managed to install glib1.2 and gtk+1.2 from the deb files, even though in many forums they say that it is incompatible with newer Ubuntu versions. Although, it was needed to install first the glib1.2.deb second the libgtk+1.2-common.deb and lastly (because it has as a dependency the common.deb)the libgtk+1.2.deb. In case someone else needs to install old programms on Ubuntu and needs the gtk+1.2 version it is recommended to install also the glib1.2-dev.deb and gtk+1.2-dev.deb because in that way gtk-config is also installed and needed by old programms.